# jQuery UI dialog - how to make it not closable?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, dialog, modal-dialog

I'm trying to use the jQuery dialog as a loading screen for ajax. I have it working very well so far but I'd like the loading screen to be not closable. However it seems the UI dialog doesn't have "closable" as an option?

How do you make it non-closable? I tried setting closeText to blank but that didn't do anything. The little 'X' still shows up on the upper right corner.

Don't you think closable should be an option for the dialog widget?

Thanks

Answer (score 8):

Ying, just pass a callback function to `beforeclose`:

```
$("#loading").dialog({
  beforeclose: function(){ return false }
  // other options here
});
```

Comment: Right, sorry. That is exactly what I would have suggested had you not found that part on your own. Glad it worked for you! Be sure to mark the answer as accepted (click the grey check). We both get rep points and it helps future people with the same problem know what solution worked for you. Welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: Oops, I found an issue with this solution. When I call $("#loading").dialog('close') now it does nothing. I needed that to work so I decided just to hide the "X" via css.

Answer (score 6):

Doug, thanks for the quick reply. That disabled close action. However, it did not hide the "X" on the upper right corner. I ended up using css to hide the "X".

```
/* hide the close x on loading screen */
.classForMyDialog .ui-dialog-titlebar-close {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: You should also consider setting closeOnEscape to false, 
`$( ".selector" ).dialog({ closeOnEscape: false });` on initialization
or `$( ".selector" ).dialog( "option", "closeOnEscape", false );` later to set it to false

Answer (score 2):

I think Ying is on the right track but it turns out that the `.classForMyDialog` (assuming it's the div with dialog content) doesn't have the icon as a child so it didn't work.

I had success with:

```
$("#myDialogDivID").parent().find(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").hide()
```

The parent selects the dialog envelop `div` and then we can find and hide the close icon.

I also take this opportunity to highlight the comment to set:

```
closeOnEscape: false
```

Answer (score 1):

How I got about it thanks to Ying and Doug

Class:

```
.myDialog .ui-icon{
    display:none !important;
}
```

Jquery:

```
$(".ajaxloader").dialog({
        modal:true,
        resizable:false,
        dialogClass:'myDialog'
    });
```

Comment: This does hide the icons on the dialog itself as well. The selector should be more concrete I believe.

Answer (score 0):

For a demonstration of how I used jQueryUI dialog as a loading screen.

http://pure-essence.net/2010/01/29/jqueryui-dialog-as-loading-screen-replace-blockui/